# How do you write this logarithmic question in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode

How can I convert the image below into TeX?

[image: Logarithm Problem]

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Haven't tried anything... the change of base is something which I haven't learned how to do.

Comment: Do you want to *solve* the problem or *print* it?

Comment: I want to print it.

Comment: How about `\log_{2}`?

Answer (score 16):

This is simple: the logarithmic function is `\log`, so you want something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Find $n$ given that
\[
\log_{2} 3 \, \log_{3} 4 \, \log_{4} 5 \, \dotsm \, \log_{n} (n+1)=10
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, this is a case where `amsmath` needs a little help, so `\dotsm` should be used to denote “dots for multiplication”. Also I added thin spaces to reduce the clutter.

The answer is, of course, 1023.

If you fear that the above can be ambiguous, then use `\cdot` (and `\dotso` in order not to have a series of five centered dots):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Find $n$ given that
\[
\log_{2} 3 \cdot \log_{3} 4 \cdot \log_{4} 5 \cdot \dotso \cdot \log_{n}(n+1)=10
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]